# Performance issue in phonegap and Jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

I got some performance issues in phonegap 3.0. i got two html pages (i dont want to put together as one page). Both pages called jquery mobile script and deviceready function for phonegap. i use navigation command like window.location = "page2.html".

It can go to page2.html but it will take 7 seconds (I thought It is loaded script files again). so i tried to use window.location.href="page2.html". it is straight away go to page2 within 1 sec but it cannot be called page onload function (aka : $(document).ready()) in the page2.

How should i solve this issue? thanks for any suggestion or help !

Edited:

page1.html header funcition

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/less-1.3.0.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.1.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="css/style.css">
    <div>
    Please click here to <a style="font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;color:blue;" id="registerButton"  
onclick="callanotherpage('page2.html');" >REGISTER</a> !
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(init);

function init(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
         },true);

      $("#pageLoader").hide();

}

function callanotherpage(page_name){
    window.location.replace(page_name);
  }
```

In page2.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/less-1.3.0.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(init);

    function init(){
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
             },true);

          $("#pageLoader").hide();

    }

    function callanotherpage(page_name){
        window.location.replace(page_name);
      }

</script>
```

Best Rgds,
dartfrog

Answer (score 0):

What about using just a normal link?

```
<a href="page2.html">link</a>
```

i have an application with 9000 lines of code on 3 different html pages. Every page has more than 9000 lines. The change from one site to another does not take longer than < 1sec

Comment: Hi Bro, are you using PhoneGap 3.x ?

Comment: Nope, i'm using Cordova 3.5. If you want to know, how to get started with that you can have a look into the Cordova CLI Guide. I would prefer Cordova, but thats your choice, with what you want to work.

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

Comment: Hi Bro, but when i use window.location.href = "page2.html", it can go less than a sec. but it will not be called page load function of page2.html. still confuse ??

Comment: Dartfrog what about some Code?

Comment: I Edited my question. but i found out some facts. when go to another page, the log showed that "resetting plugin due to page load". I thought this is the main issue.

Comment: Hi Sithys, i solved rdy. it is because of the javascript file, less-1.3.0.min.js. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
document.location = "page2.html";
```